# How do I turn off the BULB and LIVE TIME mode of my OLYMPUS OM-D EM-5?

Tags: camera-settings, olympus

I have recently purchased an Olympus OM-D EM-5. I did some research and playing around and figured out how to use the camera and the options I wanted.

Everything was working fine, I was using the manual option and taking some good shots, but after taking the camera back off of my sister, I noticed that my manual settings now had BULB/LIVE TIME on. After doing many hours of research, reading the manual, resetting my camera, playing with the camera settings, etc, etc I still have no idea how to turn it off, so that I can just use the normal, basic manual settings.

Comment: Are there any buttons (Fn 1/2 or REC) assigned to bulb mode? I'd suggest to do a **FULL** reset rather than just a *Basic* reset. Have you tried both of those?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any buttons assigned to bulb mode. Yes, actually I did a FULL reset but that didn't change anything either.

Comment: Hi! You can actually answer your own questions -- that's better than leaving the answer in a comment.

Comment: FYI on the flag... Mods cannot convert comments to answers, just the other way around.

Comment: Isn't that explained in the camera's manual?

Answer (score 1):

(From a comment by the original poster, who hasn't returned to make it an answer. Post marked as community wiki.)

Goods news! My sister just fixed this issue for me. What I didn't realise was that it still had the normal manual settings, and all I had to do was turn the main dial until it wasn't in BULB mode, or in LIVE TIME mode. But the reason why I didn't realise the was the normal manual settings was because the ISO number at the bottom had changed to inches. I just turned the dial to lower the ISO since it was much too high, and to change it back from being in inches. I took some photo's with it and realised it was the same manual settings I was using before. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I expect the Bulb to be available only in manual (M) or speed (S) mode did you try to change to the aperture A) or program (P) mode?